# Facing Issues With Ajax Update On Page Load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I'm having troubles getting content displayed on page load using ajax. The ajax is calling the right action in the respective controller. The first part of the action code where i update the database is working fine. But the part where i'm calling renderPartial is not working.

**EDIT***

Ok here is the controller action ::

```
public function actionUpdateProductData() {
    Yii::import('application.components.DataScraper.*');
    require_once('GetProductData.php');

    $productRealTime = RealTime::model()->findAll();



    if (count($productRealTime) === 0) {

        $symbolData = new GetProductData();
        $symbolData->getAmazonProductData();
    } else {


        echo CJSON::encode( array(
            'status' => 'OK',
            'div' => $this->renderPartial('_productDataGrid', array(
                            'model' => $productRealTime), 
                            true, true ),
        ));

    }
}
```

The if part is working fine. But the else portion is not working.

Here is the view index.php::

```
    <?php
        /*
         * Include the ajax Stock update script
         * 
         */
        $baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl;
        $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
        $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/ajaxProductDataUpdate.js');
?>

<div>
    <hr>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Product Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
</div>



<div class="span-10">

    <div id="section2">

    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the partial view file _productDataGrid.php

```
 <?php

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'real-time-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'category',
        'price'
        'rating'

        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

And here is the jQuery file which is making the ajax request

```
    var productParameters = {
    ajaxUpdate: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ProductAnalysis/index.php/realTime/updateProductData",
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"json",
            error: function(xhr, tStatus, e) {
                if (!xhr) {
                    alert(" We have an error ");
                    alert(tStatus + "   " + e.message);
                } else {
                    alert("else: " + e.message); // the great unknown
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update('real-time-grid', {
                    data: $(this).serialize()
                });
            }
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    productParameters.ajaxUpdate();

});
```

Upon loading the page /realTime/index.php i'm getting an error which says

```
    else:
undefined
```

Obviously the ajax call is failing, but i don't know how will i fix it. Also in Firebug, the echo date() function in the controller is working, but the Gridview is not working.

Please provide some help on how to solve this. Let me know where i'm doing wrong. I can't seem to make any headway around this.

Thanks in advance,

Maxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the gridview widget won't work with findall(). So i changed the dataprovider to simple model and it works now.

Here is the working code ::

```
public function actionUpdateStockData() {
    Yii::import('application.components.DataScraper.*');
    require_once('GetStockData.php');
    $productRealTime = new RealTime();


    if (count($productRealTime->model()->findAll()) === 0) {

        $symbolData = new GetproductData();
        $symbolData->getAmazonProductData();
    } else {


        echo CJSON::encode( array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'div' => $this->renderPartial('_productDataGrid', array(
                            'model' => $productRealTime), 
                            true, true ),
        ));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `actionUpdateStockData()` is echoing the date before the actual JSON content is encoded. As a result you're not transmitting correct JSON, and XHR will fail.

Remove the `echo date ...` line and you should be fine. And as you're just at it - you should add some response for the case where `count(RealTime::model()->findAll()) === 0`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried that but still i'm getting else: undefined. Should i make any changes to the Gridview.

Comment: And yes i will add some response to the if part. Its just i'm developing the code at present. And i'm adding all the required functionalities. The if part is working fine btw. Its the else part which is the cause of trouble.